# Passing Null values into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

I have written a service that reads XML files from a directory creates objects out of the data and passes the data into the database. I had this working before but for some reason the service is now creating a table row however its inserting 0's into the database automatically instead of the data from the XML files. My code is as follows:

This web service method fires the `XMLloader` class:

```
[WebMethod]
public void RunService()
{
    //Call XML loader to get collection of XML documents 
    foreach (GamePlay value in XMLLoader.Start())
    {
        value.addNewGamePlay();
    }
    //call inject data method for each collection
}
```

This `XMLLoader` class returns the array of `GamePlay` objects:

```
public static Array Start()
{
   string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\bradleya\Desktop\XML\");
   List<GamePlay> gameObj = new List<GamePlay>(); 

   foreach (string value in filePaths)
   {
      XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
      xd.Load(value);
      XmlNode documentNode = xd.SelectSingleNode("/GamePlayData/GamePlay");

      GamePlay newGame = new GamePlay();
      newGame.setType(Convert.ToString(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText));
      newGame.setGamePlayID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GamePlayID").InnerText));
      newGame.setParticipantID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("ParticipantID").InnerText));
      newGame.setGameVersionID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameVersionID").InnerText));
      newGame.setGameID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameID").InnerText));
      newGame.setGameScenarioID(Convert.ToInt32(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("GameScenarioID").InnerText));
      newGame.setStartDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Start").InnerText));
      newGame.setEndDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("End").InnerText));
      newGame.setSuccess(Convert.ToBoolean(documentNode.SelectSingleNode("Success").InnerText));

      gameObj.Add(new GamePlay(gameObj));
   }

   return gameObj.ToArray();
}
```

This method is fired in the object class that passes the object variable to the data access layer:

```
public void addNewGamePlay()
{
    // dataaccess method call to add GamePlay
    // (from the DB) is then set for the object
    DataAccessConn.createNewGamePlay(this.ParticipantID, this.GameVersionID, this.GameID, this.GameScenarioID, this.StartDateTime, this.EndDateTime, this.success);
}
```

Finally the data is passed into the database via the data access layer method here:

```
public static void createNewGamePlay(int ParticipantID, int GameVersionID,int GameID,int GameSenarioID,DateTime Start,DateTime End,Boolean success)
{
   SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();
   oConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=SNICKERS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=VervePhaseOne;Integrated Security=True";

   oConn.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = oConn;
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.CommandText = "addGamePlay";

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParticipantID", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@ParticipantID"].Value = ParticipantID;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameVersionID", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@GameVersionID"].Value = GameVersionID;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameID", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@GameID"].Value = GameID;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GameScenarioID", SqlDbType.Int));
   cmd.Parameters["@GameScenarioID"].Value = GameSenarioID;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Start", SqlDbType.DateTime));
   cmd.Parameters["@Start"].Value = DateTime.Now;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime));
   cmd.Parameters["@End"].Value = DateTime.Now;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@success", SqlDbType.Bit));
   cmd.Parameters["@success"].Value = success;

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The XML file I'm trying to pass is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<GamePlayData>
  <GamePlay>
    <type>add</type>
    <GamePlayID>1</GamePlayID>
    <ParticipantID>1</ParticipantID>
    <GameVersionID>1</GameVersionID>
    <GameID>1</GameID>
    <GameScenarioID>1</GameScenarioID>
    <Start>22/01/2012 23:59:59</Start> 
    <End>22/01/2012 23:59:59</End> 
    <Success>False</Success> 
  </GamePlay>
</GamePlayData>
```

Just to clarify - My issue is my service is creating a table row however the variables are setting automatically to 0. Anyone know why this would be from the code?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT -- As requested store procedure added, thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addGamePlay]
@ParticipantID int,
@GameVersionID int,
@GameID int,
@GameScenarioID int,
@Start dateTime,
@End dateTime,
@Success varchar(10)
AS
INSERT INTO GamePlay(ParticipantID,GameVersionID,GameID,GameScenarioID,StartDateTime,EndDateTime,Success)
VALUES (@ParticipantID,@GameVersionID,@GameID,@GameScenarioID,@Start,@End,@Success)
return @@identity
```

Comment: Please show your stored procedure as well

Comment: added it under edits, thanks for looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your array.Start methods should this line:

```
gameObj.Add(new GamePlay(gameObj));
```

be :

```
gameObj.Add(newGame);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not adding `newGame` to your list after you've hydrated it from the XML file:

```
gameObj.Add(new GamePlay(gameObj));
```

I think should be:

```
gameObj.Add(newGame);
```

Comment: I swear this was working last week :( that was the problem, thanks a lot guys. Saved me a day of heartache.

Answer (score 0):

i think all the places in which you are encountering a 0 instead or null are simple int types
this happens because there can be no null values for values types in .Net and actually 0 is the null values of an int
so you should probably change the definition of `GamePlay` class from using `int` to `int?` OR `Nullable<int>`